# RootViewController - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath - Load image from assetsLibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, image, objective-c-blocks, alasset

StackOverflow friends and colleague programmers,

My RootViewController (a flowerTableView on a view) should display cell's with title, subtitle and an image thumbnail (loaded from the camera roll).  A very basic table I guess.

All content is stored in 'Core Data' but the images are stored as imagePaths to the camera roll. Example: `flower.imagePath = assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000002&ext`

Using the code at the bottom everything should run smoothly but it doesn't . When starting the App the title's and subtitle's are shown, but the images are not. When I press a cell, which display's the detail view, and pop back again to the main view the image for this specific cell is shown.

When I press 'Show All', a button on a toolbar which executes the following code

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:nil];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
[self.flowerTableView reloadData];
```

and reloads the table, all the beautiful flowers are now shown.

Why didn't the flowers be displayed the first time? Is this a caching problem?

When debugging this code the string: 'This debug string was logged after this function was done' was logged after loading the table on starting the app, not after pressing 'Show All'
This means that all images are loaded from the camera roll successfully but attached to the cell after the cell was displayed and therefore not shown.

The same line is printed as intended when pressing 'Show All'

Hope someone can tell me what's going on here and even better, what to change in my code to make this work. I'm stuck at the moment...

Thank for helping me out!
Edwin

:::THE CODE:::

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Flower *flower = [fetchedResultsController_ objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    // Display the image if one is defined
    if (flower.imagePath && ![flower.imagePath isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        // Should hold image after executing the resultBlock
       __block UIImage *image = nil;

        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *asset)
        {
            NSLog(@"This debug string was logged after this function was done");
            image = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] retain];
        };

        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock  = ^(NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error: %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        };

        [assetsLibrary_ assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:flower.imagePath] 
                        resultBlock:resultBlock
                       failureBlock:failureBlock];

        [cell.imageView setImage:image];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

-[ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock] runs asynchronously. That means that the call returns immediately in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. The cell is displayed in the table view before the actual loading of the asset has taken place.

What you need to do is set the image for the cell in the result block. Something like this:

```
if (flower.imagePath && ![flower.imagePath isEqualToString:@""])
{
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *asset)
    {
        NSLog(@"This debug string was logged after this function was done");
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];

        //this line is needed to display the image when it is loaded asynchronously, otherwise image will not be shown as stated in comments
        [cell setNeedsLayout]; 

    };

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock  = ^(NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error: %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    };

    [assetsLibrary_ assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:flower.imagePath] 
                    resultBlock:resultBlock
                   failureBlock:failureBlock];
}
```

Comment: Also, please be aware that the format of Asset URLs may change between versions of iOS. You are storing asset URLs in a database but there is no guarantee that they will still work when a user upgrades to iOS5.

Comment: I also tried that line of code in accomplishing this task but due to the asynchronously execution it failed too. The images are loaded but not shown. What I need is a reloadData after table:cellForRowAtIndexPath but that will loop forever... ;-)

Comment: One more thing, I sound a bit like Colombo... If the loading of the images is done in a asynchronous matter, why, when I press on 'Show All', the exact same function is executed in the exact same way but now the images are loaded in a synchronous matter. Thus, when I did some debugging the first output would be:`-function start, -function end, -loading image`. The second output would be: `-function start, -loading image, -function end`.

Comment: The point is that the method *may* run asynchronously so you have to assume it will. It's impossible to know what ALAssetsLibrary is doing internally and exactly when the completion block will be called. For example, on the first call, ALAssetLibrary needs to check that the user has given your app access to the library and possibly show a dialog if not. It may also cache assets and return them synchronously if it can.

Comment: Thanks for you're help Robin! I will add some code to store thumbnails of the images in core data, which will be shown in the table. No more asynchronous code execution for table views anymore...

Comment: Take a look at this [sample][1] from Apple. It describes how to lazily load images in a table view. It shows loading from the network not via ALAssetsLibrary but the same principles apply.  [1]:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -1):

Fellow Overflowist let me propose the following solution:

rather than creating your cells in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

create an NSMutableArray populated with UITableViewCells (the same ones you create in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method) that you want to display in the table
and simply return the relevant UITableViewCell (which will be an object in the NSMutableArray) in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

This way the cellForRowAtIndexPath method will show cells which have already been loaded and are ready to be shown.

Comment: The point of creating cells in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method is that you can take advantage of UITableView's reuse and dequeing of cells. This means you only need to create a minimal number of cells even if your table contains thousands of rows.

Comment: Thanks for you're feedback and brain-cycles. Could you give me some code on how you would implement this? Keep in mind that 1000 records with images may be used.

Comment: Not sure who you are responding to here, Edwin, me or Zigglzworth, but don't do it like this. One of the key features of UITableView is that it will reuse cell instances. If you take Zigglzworth's advice you are bypassing this feature. Solve the original problem instead.

Comment: @Robin : obviously you can load more cells into the array as the uitableview is scrolled down you do not need to add 1000 cells to the array all at once. I have used this many times and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @Zigglzworth : Ok, but you are basically re-implementing a cell cache that UITableView offers already if you use it correctly.

Comment: @Robin :  You will most likely find that caching does not help since caching would probably only occur once the table is shown for the first time which is where the problem exists. But its worth a shot anyway.

Comment: @RobinSummerhill is right.  Yes it will work, but it's not going to scale, and it's not the way the API expects you to do things.  I think it's unhelpful to recommend to people to misuse the API, especially when their understanding of it isn't high.